# Когда появились рифмы в стихах

Tags: поэзия

А когда у где появились в стихах рифмы? Почитаешь стихи античных авторов, там никакой рифмы. Восточные (танки, хокку) — тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почитаешь стихи античных авторов, там никакой рифмы.

В стихах христианских поэтов IV в. Амвросия Медиоланского и Пруденция ассонансы преходят иногда в полнозвучные рифмы. Однако рифмы в полной мере ввёл в латинские стихи в V в. поэт Седулий, который и был тем «глухим ребёнком» и «сумасшедшим негром», которых Поль Верлен считал изобретателем рифмы.[1](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B0)

([Вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B0))

Там есть и ответы на возможные вопросы в отношении появления рифм в стихотворной традиции других языков и народов, копировать или пересказывать считаю тут невозможным уже по размеру. Поскольку речь идет о фактах, а не их трактовке, я склонен доверять источнику.

Но вообще надо сказать, что для теории поэзии гораздо большее значение имеет не сама рифма, а формы ей создаваемые за счет структуры чередований.

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)

> ссылку на Чернова.

Увы, трудно. Журнал "Юность", если не ошибаюсь, крохотная заметка 1972 или 1973 г. И упоминание в МК того же времени. Это самая первая его работа, ученическая, он её, кажется, даже в список публикаций не включал. Я с ней еще в школе столкнулся, как раз когда перестали долбить "Слово" - на несколько месяцев опоздал. 
 Потом ЛГ - конца семидесятых, это уже было вполне серьёзно, но оригинала тоже нет. В сети есть только косвенные сслыки на неё (http://gerodot.ru/viewtopic.php?t=3225) и авторский перевод "Слова" в четырех или более редакциях.

Я обещаю, что если найду - всенепременно. А послушать его реконструкции можно здесь. 
http://www.kozma.ru/library/authors/chernov/word.htm

А вообще про рифму в "Слове" он понаписал столько, что любой поисковик Вам даст ответы. Там выше, на геродоте, есть ссылка на одну работу, касающуюся, в том числе, и рифмы "Слова".
А, вот, http://feb-web.ru/feb/slovo/critics/isl/isl-270-.htm

Простите, у меня третий день некоторый цейтнот и хронические проблемы с инетом. Всё что могу сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: Да не за что. Я так понимаю, вопрос-то требовал гораздо более конкретного  ответа. Увы...  

Я немного отредактировал, не знаю, до или после Вашего прочтения.

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно точно сказать, в какой национальной литературе возникло это явление, потому что представления о рифме исторически изменчивы. В античной литературе европейского юга будущую рифму с её функцией отмечать границы соотносимых речевых отрезков (фраз или стихов) замещал гомеотелевтон – приём подбора слов с однозвучными окончаниями, а в раннесредневековой поэзии европейского севера – аллитерация). В современном виде рифма впервые распространилась по Европе благодаря поэзии трубадуров в 10-12 веках. Есть три гипотезы о появлении у них рифмы согласно первой рифма была заимствована из средневековой латинской литературы, где она отчётливо проявилась в 9–10 вв.; по второй рифма заимствована у арабов Испании, т. к. в арабской поэзии рифма распространилась в 8 в.; третья – рифма заимствована из устного творчества кельтов, в ирландской и валлийской (т. е. кельтской) поэзии уже к 8 в. были рифмы. Можно добавить, что явление рифмы в той или иной степени известно всем народам и рифмы могли зарождаться в разных национальных культурах вполне самостоятельно.

Comment: А как насчет источника всего этого?
Неужели сами все читали от арабов до кельтов? 

На самом деле сколько там ни рассуждай о понятии рифмы, у римлян она была вполне себе полнозвучная.

Это не рифма?  
  
Per tot discrimina rеrum  
Nequidquam erepte periclis?  
Manet alta mente repostum  
Quam forti pectore et armis    
  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81_%28%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%29
(там есть ссылка на сборник стихов).

Флавий Феликс, конец пятого века

Comment: 2. Salve, nec minimo puella naso,  
Nec bello pede, nec nigris ocellis,  
Nec longis digitis, nec ore sicco,  
Nec sano nimis elegante lingua,  
Decoctoris amica Formiani.  
Ten provincia narrat esse bellam,  
Tecum Lesbia nostra comparatur?  
O saecl(um) insapiens et infacetum! 

Вот вполне себе классический образец римской поэзии золотого века(I век до н. э.) найдёте рифму - сообщите. http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/sedulius.html - это ссылка на "изобретателя рифмы" Седулия. Латынь я конечно подзабыл основательно, но рифмы там тоже почему-то не заметил.

Comment: 1. А где вы рифму нашли? Транскрибирую по-русски с выделением ударных звуков:  
Пер тОт дискримИна рЕрум  
НеквИдквам эпЕрте перИклис?  
МанЕт Альта мЕнте репОстум  
Квам фОрти пектОре эт Армис   

Ну, конечно при большом желании, рифму увидеть можно, правда неточную и неглубокую и не рифму, но спорить с вами не буду, вам виднее.

Comment: >Вот вполне себе классический образец римской поэзии золотого века  
  
Не передергивайте уважаемый. Седулий жил в *пятом* веке нашей эры. Зачем мне что-то искать до РХ?

>Транскрибирую по-русски *с выделением ударных звуков*:

Зачем? Кто вам вообще сказал, что римская рифма была завязана на силлабо-тонике? *Русская* рифма была изобретена русскими, западная к размеру отношения не имеет.

>рифмы...не заметил.  
  
Вы не заметили основного. Рифма не была регулярной. 
Кстати. Рифмы в "Слове о полку Игоревом" тоже никто не видел. Пока её не нашел Андрей Чернов. Особую, правда. По *началу* строк.

Comment: Ди и "траскибируете" вы, судя по всему, неправильно. В двусложных словах ударение никогда не падает на второй слог. В многосложных словах падает  на второй от конца, если он долгий. Иначе - на третий. 
эпЕрте - ??? erepte = Эрепте (ударение на первый слог, кстати). 
 
qu - это не КВа, это огубленное К.
Вы действительно учили классическую латынь Вергилия? Или только современный медицинский суррогат?

Comment: 4. Даже при вашем способе ударения, рифмы в современном виде не выходит, а спрашивают именно про неё. Пытаться делать точную транскрипцию у меня и намерения не было и даже опечатку допустил, но qua на русский транскрибируют как правило именно как ква http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/52115/conditio  
А ударение в латинских стихах, обусловлено во многом ритмом стиха, у приведённого мной выше Катулла в первой строчке тоже почти все ударения на последний слог, что невозможно в латинском вообще.

Comment: behemothus! Если не трудно. дайте. пожалуйста ссылку на Чернова.

Comment: 1. Если ставить ударение по правилам, а не по ритму будут небольшие разночтения, но даже в этом случае рифмы нет. Именно это я и имел в виду.

Comment: >обусловлено ритмом стиха, а не орфоэпией  
  
А ритм определялся чередованием долгих и кратких слогов. Они ж у греков взяли.  
  
>Даже при вашем способе ударения,  
  
Это вроде как теория. Причем азы. Нет?

Ларf, смотрите мой основной ответ, здесь не помещается.